# Is there a theory of "rings" with partially defined multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, laurent-series

Consider the abelian group $R [[\mathbb{Z}^d]]$ of all formal Laurent series over a commutative ring $R$ (a typical element has the form $\sum_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \lambda_v \cdot X_1^{v_1} \dots X_d^{v_d}$ with $\lambda_v \in R$). Since there is no restriction on the coefficients, we cannot make $R [[\mathbb{Z}^d]]$ into a ring by the usual multiplication, but we get a partially defined operation in this way. It is easy to see that $R [[\mathbb{Z}^d]]$ satisfies all ring axioms, whenever all involved terms are defined. Maybe one could call such structures "partial rings".

Is there a general theory of partial (commutative) rings which abstracts from this example? I am particularly interested in the notion of ideals and quotients of them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly are the $\lambda_v$'s?

Comment: @Nishant: $\lambda_v$ is an arbitrary element of $R$ for all $v$. In fact the elements of $R [[\mathbb{Z}^d]]$ can be identified with maps $\mathbb{Z}^d \to R$.

Comment: Okay, so why can't you multiply any two elements?

Comment: @Nishant: You can't even square all elements. Look e.g. at $\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} X^z$ for $d=1$. On the other hand there are many subgroups which form a ring by this multiplication: e.g. the set of elements with $\lambda_v = 0$ for all $v$ with a negative component (or, more generally, for all $v$ outside some pointed cone).

Comment: To be clear: The "usual multiplication" is the convolution $\left( \sum_{u \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \lambda_u \cdot X^u \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{v \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \mu_v \cdot X^v \right) := \sum_{w \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \left( \sum_{u+v = w} \lambda_u \cdot \mu_v \right) \cdot X^w$, provided that for all $w$ the set $\{(u,v) : u+v=w, \lambda_u, \mu_v \neq 0\}$ is finite. It is clear that the latter condition is not always satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

[Groupoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) in the category theory can be described as partial groups. What you are asking for is called [ringoids](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2006/09/ringoids.html), see also [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~eburkard/Talks/Ringoid%20Presentation.pdf).

Comment: Inwhat way is this object a ringoid?

Comment: In that multiplication isn't defined for all pairs of elements. Whether this example is a ringoid is a different question.

Comment: Well, the point of the question more or less clearly isto know what the full thing of Laurent series is...

Comment: Notice that addition *is* defined for all pairs of elements, and that sort of collides with the definition of ringoids.

Comment: The title question is "Is there a theory of “rings” with partially defined multiplication?", the example, correctly or not, is only an illustration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look if ringoids are the right things for my purposes. But Mariano is right: The Laurent series thing is the prototype of those objects I am considering, and the theory I am looking for should abstract from these. I am asking this question because I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is also called a preadditive category. Two useful examples of this are graded rings (the objects are the gradings, and hom(m,n) is the set of ring elements of degree $n-m$)  and the category of matrices (the objects are nonnegative integers).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a proper answer, but here's an idea:

There's a category $\mathbf{Ab}_{\mathrm{par}}$ of abelian groups and partial homomorphisms between them. You should be able to make $\mathbf{Ab}_{\mathrm{par}}$ into a symmetric monoidal category with the usual tensor product. Then define that a *partial ring* is a monoid object in $\mathbf{Ab}_{\mathrm{par}}.$ Maybe try searching for the phrase "monoid object in the the monoidal category of abelian groups with partial homomorphisms" or something like that.